# Is asyncio.loop.time() comparable with datetime.datetime.now() and how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm hoping to use an `asyncio.loop` to set callbacks at specific times.  My problem is that I need to schedule these based on `datetime.datetime` objects (UTC) but `asyncio.loop.call_at()` uses an internal reference time.

A quick test on python 3.7.3 running on Ubuntu shows that `asyncio.loop.time()` is reporting the system uptime.  For conversion my first thought is to naively store a reference time and use it later:

```
from asyncio import new_event_loop
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

_loop = new_event_loop()
_loop_base_time = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds=_loop.time())

def schedule_at(when, callback, *args):
    _loop.call_at((when - _loop_base_time).total_seconds(), callback, *args)
```

However it's not clear whether or not this offset (`datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds=loop.time())`) is stable.  I have no idea whether system up-time drifts in comparison to UTC even where the system clock is modified (eg: through NTP updates).

Bearing in mind this is for monitoring software which will potentially be running  for months at a time, small drifts might be very significant.  I should note that I've seen systems lose minutes per day without an NTP daemon and one off NTP updates can shift times by many minutes in a short space of time.  Since I don't know if the two are kept in sync, it's unclear how much I need to be concerned.

---

Note: I am aware of python's issue with scheduling events more than 24 hours in the future. I will get round this by storing distant future events in a list and polling for up-coming events every 12 hours, scheduling them only when they are < 24 hours in the future.

---

Is it possible to reliably convert from `datetime.datetime` to `asyncio.loop` times? or are the two time systems incomparable?.  If they are comparable, is there anything special I need to do to ensure my calculations are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the difference in seconds using the same time framework as the one you're using for scheduling, then use `asyncio.call_later` with the computed delay:

```py
def schedule_at(when, callback, *args):
  delay = (when - datetime.utcnow()).total_seconds()
  _loop.call_later(delay, callback, *args)
```

This would work around the question of whether the difference between the loop's time and `utcnow` is stable; it only needs to be stable between the time of scheduling the task and the time of its execution (which, according to your notes, should be less than 12 hours).

For example: if the event loop's internal clock drifts 1 second apart from `utcnow` every hour (a deliberately extreme example), you would drift at most 12 seconds per task, but you would not accumulate this error over months of runtime. Compared with the approach of using a fixed reference, this approach gives a better guarantee.

Comment: A correct count of seconds is not the problem, measuring how many seconds have passed is the problem.  It needs to be correct at the time the task is called, not just correct at the time the task is scheduled.  The problem of drift occurs where two clocks disagree on how many seconds have passed.  recomputing it within 12 hours of occurrence would of curse reduce the risk of large drift though.

Comment: This approach limits potential drift to as much as could happen between the scheduling and the execution, i.e. 12 hours, and doesn't accumulate drift errors (e.g. even if you're running for months at a time, each task recalculates the required delay when it's being scheduled). I don't think you can do any better than that, except maybe re-calibrate closer to the task's execution time (e.g. schedule a pre-execute check closer to the execution time, where you will re-compute the required delay and schedule the task there); but that seems like overkill for most practical purposes.

Comment: Coming back to this question, I've realised the reference to system uptime suggests it's based on the system [monotonic clock](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime). This is usually in-sync with the system time (as timedate.now()) but the delta is prone to large jumps if / when the system clock is adjusted. The monotonic clock is good if you want something to happen "in 10 minutes" bad if you want it "at 10 pm".  So the 1 second drift mentioned in this answer is very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach would be not to rely on a loop internal clock at all. You can run a task in background and periodically check if callback should be executed.

This method's inaccuracy corresponds to a time you wait before next check, but I don't think it's critical considering any other possible inaccuracies (like Python GC's stop-the-world, for example).

On a good side is that you aren't limited by 24 hours.

This code shows main idea:

```
import asyncio
import datetime



class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._callbacks = set()
        self._task = None

    def schedule_at(self, when, callback):        
        self._callbacks.add((when, callback,))
        if self._task is None:
            self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._checker())

    async def _checker(self):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
            self._exec_callbacks()

    def _exec_callbacks(self):
        ready_to_exec = self._get_ready_to_exec()
        self._callbacks -= ready_to_exec

        for _, callback in ready_to_exec:
            callback()

    def _get_ready_to_exec(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        return {
            (when, callback,)
            for (when, callback,)
            in self._callbacks
            if when <= now
        }


timer = Timer()


async def main():
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    s1_after = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
    s3_after = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=3)
    s5_after = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)

    timer = Timer()
    timer.schedule_at(s1_after, lambda: print('Hey!'))
    timer.schedule_at(s3_after, lambda: print('Hey!'))
    timer.schedule_at(s5_after, lambda: print('Hey!'))

    await asyncio.sleep(6)


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Isn't this basically replicating what the event loop is doing internally?

Comment: @Avish kind of like that. But it avoids loop's internal clocks and all related problems: 24 hours limit or possible drifts towards datetime.

Comment: Changed in version 3.8: In Python 3.7 and earlier with the default event loop implementation, the difference between when and the current time could not exceed one day. This has been fixed in Python 3.8.